# Merging rows in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple multi-dimensional array:

```
$carousels = array(
    array(cols=>4, visible=>"visible-lg"), 
    array(cols=>4, visible=>"visible-md"), 
    array(cols=>3, visible=>"visible-sm"), 
    array(cols=>3, visible=>"visible-xs")
    );
```

How should I approach combining any rows where 'cols' is the same?

I want to end up with the following:

```
$carousels = array(
    array(cols=>4, visible=>"visible-lg visible-md"), 
    array(cols=>3, visible=>"visible-sm visible-xs")
    );
```

So the 'visible' key is merged and the 'cols' key remains as before.  I'm thinking I need to loop through the array and output to another 'merged' array but is there a better way?

This is what I have so far

```
function searchForKey($key, $arr) {
   foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
       if ($v['cols'] === $key) {
           return $k;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
function mergeRows( $arr ) {
    $result = array();
    foreach( $arr as $k => $v ) {
        $key = searchForKey($v['cols'], $result);
        if ($key !== null) {
            $result[$key]['visible'] .= " ".$v['visible'];
        } else {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a loop. Loop the array, check if "cols" exists, if it does, concatenate the "visible" string, and if not, add a new entry. After that you will have your desired array.

array_merge would not work here because it will just merge 2 or more arrays.

Comment: That's pretty much what I had in mind. I just wondered if there existed some method to 'squash' an array in php